# Jupyter cells go blank after scrolling in Vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

[image: blank jupyter cells]

I just upgraded to the latest version of VSCODE 1.75.0, and now jupyter is not working properly in VSCODE...

I am about to uninstall everything and reinstall VSCODE and jupyter. But if there is an easier fix for this I would love to know.

I can minimize the jupyter cell and then re-open it and the code will appear, but when I scroll down and scroll back up, everything is blank.

I have tried uninstalling the jupyter vscode extension, and python extensions using
`python3 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat jupyterlab-widgets nbclient`

but it is still opening the files as a notebook somehow... so there must be an extension somewhere causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, uninstalling the entire application and re-installing it solved the problem. I noticed that it went from 1.75.0 to 1.75.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173590) on github last week.

This is the error of **VsCode 1.75.0**. You can use the latest version of 1.75.1 or use the old version to solve this problem.

You can also add the following codes to your `settings.json` so that VsCode will update by itself:

```
"update.mode": "default",
```